# Updating the checkbox state automatically does not reflect in the GUI

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a setting window containing an observable collection of roles and components. The idea here is that when you select a role on the left, it automatically checks the components associated to that role on the right. The main problem is that the action is performed correctly behind the scenes but is not reflected on the UI.

My xaml is set up with a data template to display the check boxes in a list:

```
 <ListBox Name="Components" ItemsSource="{Binding Components, Mode=TwoWay}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{DynamicResource MainForegroundColor}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5 5 0 0" />
           </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

My viewmodel code is quite simple, I create a `selectableComponent` class to hold the check box state and its information, and a role class:

```
public class SelectableComponent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
} 


public class Role
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string projectsToWatch { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<SelectableComponent> Components { get; set; }
```

The method that gets called when you change the role:

```
public void LoadSpecificRoleComponents(string role)
{

  Role r = Config.Instance.Roles.FirstOrDefault(a => string.Equals(a.Name, role, System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

  foreach (SelectableComponent sc in Components)
  {
       if (string.Equals(r.projectsToWatch, "*"))
       {
           sc.IsChecked = true;
       }
       else
       {
           sc.IsChecked = r.projectsToWatch.Contains(sc.Name, System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
       }
  }

    RaisePropertyChanged("Components");
}
```

What I don't understand is why the UI does not get updated properly. Since I do `RaisePropertyChanged("Components")` on the components, it should update.

Any type of help would be appreciated, it's probably a simple thing I am missing out on.

Comment: You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged for Name in SelectableComponent

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the components are cleared of their checked status before i go about changing their state depending on wich project need to be activated

Comment: RaisePropertyChanged("Components") is usefull if you renew the complete collection - ObservableCollection notify allready. You must change  SelectableComponent to viewmodel pattern and send NotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: After RaisePropertyChanged("Components"); is getter Components { get; set; } triggered? Place a breakpoint there to check it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5246145/3615 yes it gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectableComponent needs to implement INotifyPropetyChanged and to raise RaisePropertyChanged event for IsChecked:

```
private bool _isChecked 

public bool IsChecked { 
get{ return _isChecked;} 
set
 {
      if(_isChecked != value)
      {   _isChecked= value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: It's not mandatory to have change notification inside setter. OP called RaisePropertyChanged("Components"); from LoadSpecificRoleComponents.

Comment: that actually solved my issue, the nesting of my class made it so there was no notification of change on this property

Answer (score 0):

You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged for your SelectableComponent. Then do so:

```
private string _name = string.Empty; 
public string Name
{
    get{ return _name;}
    set 
    {
        _name = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}
```

And do the same for your ObservableCollection:

```
private ObservableCollection<Component> _componentCollection = new ObservableCollection<Component>();
public ObservableCollection<Component> Components
{
    get{ return _componentCollection; }
    set
    {
        _componentCollection = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Components");
    }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't help. Changing an observable collection item's property would not trigger notification on the collection itself.